# How to call CUDA api with optional location?

Tags: cuda

I wonder what is the best way to call those API with optional location. For example:
`CUresult cuStreamGetCaptureInfo_v2 ( CUstream hStream, CUstreamCaptureStatus* captureStatus_out, cuuint64_t* id_out, CUgraph* graph_out, const CUgraphNode** dependencies_out, size_t* numDependencies_out )` 
The document says `id_out, graph_out` are optional location. In python, if it is optional, we don't need to specify it. If i wanted to pass in only `id_out`, how can I achieve that without getting the "too few arguments" error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C or C++, for a function with a prototype like that, *all arguments must be specified* in order to get anything to compile.  This doesn't have anything to do with CUDA.

For [that particular function](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__STREAM.html#group__CUDA__STREAM_1g5e9922de8ad5e8d76fcfb4367e8e3eb0), all optional arguments are pointer arguments.  It should be safe to pass a null pointer for any "optional" argument that you don't wish to specify.